# asp.net alternative to crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

We have created forms in crystal reports using ASP.net and SQL database which display forms in PDF format.   However, we can’t control the generated PDF reports like some options that user can select/unselect one form creaed in PDF.  We are looking for an alternative solution that would give developers more control over generated PDF reports.   We love Crystal Reports and how easy it is to design the forms and looking for something similar that would enhanced UI and provide more options for developers

Comment: There are various reporting components from all the "big" third-parties: DevExpress, Telerik, ComponentOne, etc. I have never used Crystal Reports, but it might be worthwhile to explore one of these other suites (they have trials).

Comment: Have you looked at Report Runner Web Portal? http://www.reportrunner.com

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the Microsoft ReportViewer control to process RDLC reports (do not need to have an instance of the Microsoft Reporting Server installed) and then export the report to PDF. See this ([Save RDLC reports as PDF programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652203/save-rdlc-reports-as-pdf-programaticaly)) to discover how to export to PDF.

This way you get a powerfull reporting engine for free.

[Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6576)

[Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6442)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reporting_software).

Given that you are using asp.net with existing Crystal reports, [Telerik Reporting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telerik_Reporting) should definitely be worth a look.

Also, given that you are using a Microsoft technology (and particularly if your SQL is MS SQLServer), it could be worth investigating [SQLServer Reporting Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services).

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [DoddleReport](http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/)

Out of the box it can render reports to Excel, PDF, HTML, and CSV – fully pluggable of course.