# Multithreading RDLC report not refreshing

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, rdlc

Gurus
We are developing a win forms application in .NET 4.0, that generate PDF reports using RDLC control. As the report generation takes lot of time, we decided to implement Parallel for each.. With the following code , it generates the PDF for first record after that, system just hangs.. Do help us...

```
 public void generatereport()
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            DataTable dtBranch = new DataTable();
            dtBranch = getBranchNo(); -- we might get around 300 rows here

            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(dtBranch.AsEnumerable(), drow =>
                   {
                       // Shows the ReportData along with the branch code
                        reportdate = drow["reportdate"].ToString();
                       string branchName = drow["BranchNo"].ToString();
                        ProcessReport(branchName);
                   });
                  reportViewer2.Visible = false;
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "Branch Summary Generated at '" + @fullpath + "'";
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                //Console.Write(e.Data + e.Message);
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        private void ProcessReport(string branName)
        {
            if (reportViewer2.InvokeRequired)
            {
                ProcessReportCallBack d = new ProcessReportCallBack(ProcessReport);
                Invoke(d, new object[] { branName });
            }
            else
            {
                log.Debug("branch" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = getReportOrderNoBasedonBranchID(branName);//Get all the report order no as per the branch id

                    this.sp_getReportOrderNoTableAdapter.Fill(this.getRptNo.sp_getReportOrderNo, branName);
                    this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.SubreportProcessingEventHandler(this.reportViewer2_Subreport1);
                    this.reportViewer2.Clear();
                    this.reportViewer2.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                    this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Master.rdlc";
                    this.reportViewer2.Refresh();

                    Savepdf("reportViewer2", branName + "_" + reportdate);

            }
    }
```

In save PDF we are generating the PDF report..

```
byte[] bytes = null;

                bytes = reportViewer2.LocalReport.Render(
                "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
                 out extension,
                out streamids, out warnings);
                filename = BranchName + '_' + "Summary" + ".pdf";

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@fullpath + '\\' + filename, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    fs.Close();
                }
                bytes = null;
```

Kindly provide your feedback

Comment: if i understand your question, You can export to PDF without any codes by `ReportViewer`, i have 700+ rows and exported to PDF using the `Export to PDF` with `ReportViewer Control`. it takes seconds only.

Comment: can you please share sample code, we have sub report inside our main report and i am having sub report event handler where in i pass parameter from main rdlc

Comment: I'm having to do the same thing. I need to make tons of pdfs using rdlc and I have to make it multithreaded. Can you show your final code?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a sample codes to Export to PDF, when the `RDLC` is already rendered to the `ReportViewer` try to find this icon from the `ToolBars of ReportViewer Control`:

[image]

**EDIT**:

[Save RDLC reports as PDF programaticaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652203/save-rdlc-reports-as-pdf-programaticaly)

```
public void Save(ReportViewer viewer, string savePath)
{
    byte[] Bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", "", null, null, null, null, null);

    using (FileStream Stream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create)) {
        Stream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: am trying to do ti programmatic ally..no user intervention will be there

Comment: for myself generating one report it self takes around 30-45 secs...so need to generate pdfs parallaly